# New Flash 5.5 App - Best Approach

Tags: actionscript-3, file, load

I have a new app projects and was wondering, before I begin, what might be a good way to organize the data.

The idea is an app that delivers a daily question, with the question being different each day. The 365 questions could be stored in a text file and I've been working with loading a XML file into Flash and displaying results.

Would it be better to store the questions in a simple text file and load into Flash (using URL Loader) or an XML file?

The XML file may help in having 'day' info available, but there may be a better way to get the app to display the correct question for each day.

I'm working on that 'question 1' coincides with 'day 1' (of the year)

Does this approach make sense or is there a better way to have the questions available for the script to work with?

Answer (score 2):

XML would enable a data model intuitive to your goal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<questions>
    <question day="1"><![CDATA[ <b>Question 1</b>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ]]></question>
    <question day="2"><![CDATA[ <b>Question 2</b>: Consectetur adipiscing elit. ]]></question>
    <question day="3"><![CDATA[ <b>Question 3</b>: Duis semper risus nec nisi elementum. ]]></question>
</questions>
```

In ActionScript, to get the current day of the year could be implemented as:

```
public static function getDayOfTheYear(d:Date):uint {
    var firstDay:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    return (d.getTime() - firstDay.getTime()) / 86400000;
}
```

Once XML is loaded, you can use e4x to get the current question node:

```
var now:Date = new Date();
var day:uint = getDayOfTheYear(now);

/* Assuming you loaded XML to a variable: var xml:XML */
var question:XMLList = xml.question.(@day == day);
trace(question.valueOf());
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you quick response. I have the load XML part working and will apply these ideas re: date. Cheers

Comment: I have this working and displaying a question, on stage, related to the day of the year (thanks for your DOY code @Jasons). Was funny, I couldn't get anything to display until I realized that the XML file had day 1, day 2, etc. and we are up to day 212. So it was good to see a result.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you would need is a way to find out what day of the year it is. There is no native Flash API for this, so you would have to roll your own. Be aware that you would need 366 questions so that your app would work on a leap year.

As for whether to use a text file or XML, it's up to you and what you feel more comfortable with. AS3's XML API is robust, and if you're starting out in Flash this may be a good option for you.

Comment: Good point on the leap year; thanks. I'm going with XML, I like the idea of being able to add addition items in a structured way.